# How to make a grid of images?

Tags: graphics, positioning

Is it possible to place 4 images in an 2x2 grid? I don't want to float them, I don't want any captions. Each image should have the same width.

**Edit:**

Thanks for all the answers. After trying it out, I realized, that I forgot to ask one point:

Suppose I have a counter like this:

```
\newcounter{eqn}
\renewcommand*{\theeqn}{\alph{eqn})}
\newcommand{\num}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\text{\theeqn}\;}
```

Now I want to add `\num` before each picture, the enumeration should be displayed above to the left of each image.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcounter{eqn}
\renewcommand*{\theeqn}{\alph{eqn})}
\newcommand{\num}{\refstepcounter{eqn}\text{\theeqn}\;}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\putindeepbox}[2][0.7\baselineskip]{{%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}%
    \setbox0=\vbox{\noindent\hsize=\wd0\unhbox0}
    \@tempdima=\dp0
    \advance\@tempdima by \ht0
    \advance\@tempdima by -#1\relax
    \dp0=\@tempdima
    \ht0=#1\relax
    \box0
}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

% \setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \num\putindeepbox[7pt]{\includegraphics{whatever.jpg}}
    & \num\putindeepbox[7pt]{\includegraphics{whatever.jpg}} \\
  \num\putindeepbox[7pt]{\includegraphics{whatever.jpg}}
    & \num\putindeepbox[7pt]{\includegraphics{whatever.jpg}} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

(Edited to include pseudo-captions; the macro `\putindeepbox` takes something and puts it into a box of height equal to `0.7\baselineskip` by default (i.e., the height of a `\strut`) and deep enough to accomodate for the given material.  Somehow in `tabular` `\baselineskip` gets reset to zero, so I've hardcoded the height manually.  Not very elegant, but works - feel free to improve it;).  Notice also some dirty tricks with boxes - hopefully someone will find a cleaner way to do it.  I hope that this is what you wanted, and that it is not too late...  See also comments below to make spacing better.)

The spacing is not perfect; you can manipulate the horizontal spacing with `tabcolsep`, AFAIK there is no such parameter for vertical spacing in tabular.

Comment: You could use `\usepackage[demo]{graphics}` to avoid needing a 'real' image at all.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about that functionality, thanks!  I'll modify my code above.

Comment: You might also want to change `{cc}` to `{@{..}c@{..}c@{..}}` where `..` is some space command like `\hspace{<length>}`, in order to control the exact horizontal distance between the images. A `\rule[<length>]{0pt}{0pt}` can be used to add a negative space inside the top row to push the bottom row down.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, you made me embarrassed for all the upvotes I've got...  Still, ConTeXt support for this kind of things is what I perceive as much cleaner - my `tabular` solution is in fact a not-so-clean trick.

Comment: @mbork Is it possible to implement in your solution what I described in my edit above, too?

Comment: Is there some for -loop option for this?

Comment: @user4011: I'm sorry, somehow I missed your question...  I've edited my answer.

@hhh: see e.g. the `pgffor` package.

Comment: You might want to look at the `adjustbox` package. Or use `\raisebox{-\dimexpr\height+\ht\strutbox\relax}{\includegraphics{...}}` instead of that complicated computation. With `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` it becomes `\includegraphics[valign=t]{...}`

Answer (score 13):

Here is a ConTeXt solution:

```
\useMPlibrary [dum]  % for placeholder pictures
\starttext

\startcombination [2*2]
    {\externalfigure[placeholder]}{a}
    {\externalfigure[placeholder]}{b}
    {\externalfigure[placeholder]}{c}
    {\externalfigure[placeholder]}{d}
\stopcombination

\stoptext
```

The result is:[image: result]

When captions are not necessary, simply leave the second braces empty. The distance between the images can be set up with the command `\setupcombinations`, see [setupcombinations reference](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Reference/en/setupcombinations).

Comment: I really love the way ConTeXt handles this case

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. I almost feel guilty that it's so simple. TeX is supposed to make me suffer and make me feel grateful when something comes out how I wanted!

Answer (score 10):

Well, if you do not have captions, use just `\includegraphics`:

```
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{one}\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{two}\\[2em]
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{three}\hspace{0.2\textwidth}%
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{four}\par
```

Answer (score 10):

For even distribution on either side of the images, use a combination of `\hfill`s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}

Here is some text.\strut

\noindent\null\hfill\includegraphics{one} \hfill
\includegraphics{two} \hfill\null

\noindent\null\hfill\includegraphics{three} \hfill
\includegraphics{four} \hfill\null

Here is some more text.
\end{document}​
```

`\null` is to fool LaTeX in thinking there's something there from which to add the horizontal fill. `\strut` is used to improve the `\baselineskip` from the top paragraph, since it has no descenders (p, or q, or the like). You can set the image width, of course, using the `width=<len>` key-value pair of the `\includegraphics` command.

The `demo` option to [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) is merely for display purposes, allowing to typeset an image as a 150pt x 100pt black rectangle regardless of whether the image exists or not.

Comment: This only works if your images happen to be half a page wide. Needs to have [width=0.4\textwidth] or some such.