# A grid of images to fill A4 -paper for economic printing with some space for scissors

Tags: graphics, positioning, loops, printing

I want to print a A4 paper full of the same QR image. I want more elegant way to this answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37478/2956), yes I can get it working like that but I want to leave just enough space for scissors and no space near the edges and equal spacing (and is it possible to do that with for -loop or otherwise simpler?) -- possible?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Look, ma! No loops! :)

Borrowed from the TeXbook, exercise 21.8 (p. 225).

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\sbox0{%
  \includegraphics{image}%
  \kern2mm
  \vrule width 0pt depth 2mm}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\null
\cleaders\hbox to\textwidth{\leaders\copy0\hfill}\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need to learn to save votes for moments like this one. `:)` A tear of joy fell from my eye. A true *capolavoro*! I wish I could vote it 10 times. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda Just DEK's code adapted to the situation.

Comment: Your image has white space around it. Try putting it into an `\fbox` to see how much. With the macros I proposed, there are exactly 2mm between images.

Comment: @hhh I've changed the image, so that you can see the effect when there are no white borders around it.

Comment: sorry but I cannot get it running, found the book [here](http://net.ytu.edu.cn/share/%D7%CA%C1%CF/texbook.pdf). Can you describe the procedure to get such picture like Werner?

Comment: @hhh I believed that you already had the QRcode.

Comment: @hhh GIF files are not supported by TeX programs. Convert it to PNG.

Comment: @hhh Probably the image is too big. Check its dimensions with the `\fbox` method I mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

Here is one way using the [`forloop` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop) which implements an elementary nested/recursive for loop using counters. Given some counter `<cnt>`, the interface

```
\forloop[<step>]{<cnt>}{<start>}{<condition>}{<loop content>}
```

initializes `<cnt>` to `<start>` and executes `<loop content>` until `<condition>` is met. An optional first parameter `<step>` (default is `1`) can be set to modify the counter step size:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{forloop}% http://ctan.org/pkg/forloop
\usepackage{pst-barcode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-barcode
\pagestyle{empty}% No page headers/footers
\begin{document}
\setlength{\baselineskip}{2cm}%
\newcounter{qrcodesA}\newcounter{qrcodesB}%
\forloop{qrcodesA}{0}{\value{qrcodesA}<12}{% Rows
  \noindent%
  \forloop{qrcodesB}{0}{\value{qrcodesB}<9}{% Columns
    \psbarcode{tex.stackexchange.com}{}{qrcode}\hspace{2cm}}\hspace*{\fill}\\%
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

Using `\psbarcode` directly creates a dimensionless object (width and height of `0pt`). The spacing of `2cm` is arbitrary, as is the setting for `\baselineskip`. You can modify this to suit your scissor-cutting expertise.

This requires a `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` or `xelatex` compilation sequence.

Comment: ...this covers the corners/sides apparently +1.

Comment: @hhh: You can modify the row and column counters, as well as the margins set by `geometry`. I chose `margin=1cm`, but you can reduce that to your liking as long as your printer can handle it. Is that what you're referring to by "covering the corners/sides"?

Comment: there is no "includegraphics"? This is nice! It generates the images directly from the text! (needless to have middle image) Is it possible to output the ps to image formats such as png?

Comment: @hhh: The picture is *generated* by LaTeX via the package `pst-barcode`. It has a function (or command) `\psbarcode{...}{}{qrcode}` which generates the output since the [structure for producing QR codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code) is known. The benefit of producing it on-the-fly means that you can literally create your own QR code for every image that you produce, rather than have them all the same. My code produces the exact same QR code, pointing to [TeX.SX](http://tex.stackexchange.com). Yes, you can port the output to an image form.

Comment: @hhh: You won't be able to output *directly* to PNG, but you can output to PS or PDF and convert to PNG. Also, this holds for either the entire page (as in my example), or a single QR code.

Answer (score 6):

You can loop using Knuth's `\loop` and `\repeat`. Here some minimal code. You will need to experiment with the gutter between the images, as well as the numbers and scaling of the image.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=.1cm, left=0.1cm,bottom=.1cm,right=0.1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\qcode{\includegraphics{./graphics/qrcode}}
\parindent0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}
\loop
\qcode
\stepcounter{cnt}
\ifnum\thecnt<185
\repeat
\end{document}
```

Here is the result. You can also print the qrcode with LaTeX using pstricks.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to compute the number that can fit on one line based on the `\WidthOfImage`, and the number of rows based on the `\HeightOfImage` (adjusting for the spacing required by the scissors):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newlength{\Separation}%
\setlength{\Separation}{0.1cm}% Space for the "scissors"

\newlength{\WidthOfImage}%
\setlength{\WidthOfImage}{2.0cm}%

\newlength{\HeightOfImage}%
\setlength{\HeightOfImage}{2.0cm}%

\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumberOfRows}{\textheight/(\HeightOfImage+\Separation)}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\NumberOfColumns}{\textwidth/(\WidthOfImage+\Separation)}%

\begin{document}
%NumberOfRows = \NumberOfRows\par
%NumberOfColumns = \NumberOfColumns\par
%
\foreach \x in {1,...,\NumberOfRows}{\noindent%
    \foreach \y in {1,...,\NumberOfColumns}{%
        \includegraphics[width=\WidthOfImage,height=\HeightOfImage]{image}%
        \hspace{\Separation}%
    }%
    \newline%
}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multido,pst-barcode}
\def\xstrut{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
\parindent=0pt
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\multido{\iA=0+1}{54}{% 
  \makebox[2cm]{\xstrut\psbarcode{tex.stackexchange.com}{}{qrcode}} }
\end{document}
```