# Include adjacent PDF slides from two different sources through \includepdf

Tags: page-breaking, pdfpages

I would like to include pages from two different PDF files on a single page, side by side (possibly using `nup=2x2`).
Presently, there is a page ejected before each `\includepdf`.

Comment: This question could be of interest: [How to make a grid of images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37474/how-to-make-a-grid-of-images/)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's always good if you give a little more details on your issues so that it is clear what exactly you need. Here it is hard to see if you just want one page each from two different PDFs or have more. It's often good to show the code you already tried and build a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 11):

Simply use `\includepdfmerge` instead of `\includepdf`.
It inserts pages of several external PDF documents. It should allow `nup=2x2` as part of its options.

From the `pdfpages` manual, page 8:

> `\includepdfmerge[<key=val>]{<file-page-list>}`
>
> - `<key=val>` -- A comma separated list of options using the
>            `<key>=<value>` syntax.
> - `<file-page-list>` -- `<filename>[,<page spec>][,<file-page-list>]`
>     A comma separated list of filenames and optional
>     `<page spec>` specifiers. A `<page spec>` can be everything
>     the option `pages` accepts. Leading and trailing spaces
>     of items in the list is stripped.

So if you want to have pages X till Y from `A.pdf` and pages Z till V from `B.pdf` in a 2x2 grid use:

```
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x2]{A,X-Y,B,Z-V}
```

e.g.:

```
\includepdfmerge[nup=2x2]{A,1-2,B,1-2}
```

Will first use pages 1 and 2 of `A.pdf` and then pages 1 and 2 from `B.pdf` in a 2x2 grid.

---

Guessing from your example code in your comment I guess you need the following:

```
\includepdf[nup=2x2,frame,landscape]{%
  c:/Victor/Research/Presentations/Beamer-Presentations/Dam-Nonlinear.pdf,34-40,%
  c:/Victor/Research/Pdf-Library/Saouma/ASCE-Cyclic-Joint-Model.pdf,1,%
  c:/Victor/Research/Pdf-Library/Saouma/ASCE-Cyclic-Joint-Test.pdf,1%
}
```

(I broke it over several lines for readability, which is not required in your document.)

Comment: @victor: Glad I could help you. Note that you can accept the answer which helped you most by clicking on the check-mark at the top left of the answer, just below of the voting arrows. Don't forget to up-vote all good answers, too.

Answer (score 2):

When using `\includegraphics`, you can specify `page=<n>` and only include that specific page of the multi-page document. So, for example, you could use

```
\noindent%
\includegraphics[page=20,width=.5\textwidth]{file1}%
\includegraphics[page= 5,width=.5\textwidth]{file2}%
```

to include page 20 of `file1.pdf` and page 5 of `file2.pdf` side-by-side.

Comment: No this does not work either, I get each page of my pdf on a separate output page  ``\section{Fracture}
\includepdf[pages={34-40},nup=2x2,frame,frame,landscape]{c:/Victor/Research/Presentations/Beamer-Presentations/Dam-Nonlinear.pdf}
\noindent
\includepdf[pages={1},width=0.4\linewidth,frame]{c:/Victor/Research/Pdf-Library/Saouma/ASCE-Cyclic-Joint-Model.pdf}
\includepdf[pages={1},width=0.4\linewidth,frame]{c:/Victor/Research/Pdf-Library/Saouma/ASCE-Cyclic-Joint-Test.pdf}``

Comment: That is the way to go if you only have two pages you want to include side-by-side, but it seems the OP wants to have several more pages from different PDFs in a 2x2 matrix.

Comment: @victor: Note that I'm using `\includegraphics` and not `\includepdf`. Mine (the former) would work for a page-by-page inclusion. Anything bigger and Martin's answer is better-suited.

Comment: Werner, @victor: Just to point it out: `\includepdf` (and `\includepdfmerge`) uses `\includegraphics` internally and will pass all other options along to it.