# Image row in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics

A presentation contains a huge amount of images. Therefor it would be nice if one can insert a row of images on the bottom of the slide. If the item apprears the corresponding image for instance is no longer grayscale.

Is there a package to make a row of images in a beamer presentation?

For instance I have a slide:

```
\begin{frame}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
  \item Cat
  \item Dog
  \item Horse
 \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
```

The bottom of the frame should contain three images (cat, dog, horse). When the cat item appears the cat image appears at the bottom, the same effect for the dog and horse.

Comment: What do you mean by “row of images”? Something like in this question?: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37474/how-to-make-a-grid-of-images

Comment: A horizontal bar that contains a set of images (all in one row). Of course one could paint the images in TikZ. I'm looking for a way to put that bar at the bottom of each slide and an elegant way to let images appear.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `overlayarea` and overlay specifications:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
  \item Lion
  \item Cat
 \end{enumerate}

\vfill

\begin{overlayarea}{\textwidth}{2cm}
\only<1>{\centering\includegraphics[height=2cm]{ctanlion}\par}
\only<2>{\centering\includegraphics[height=2cm]{cat}\par}
\end{overlayarea}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: Well the images below should change each slide, but become active when a part of the slide appears (an enumerate item). However if I can remove the footer images, i could simply add others after each slide.

Comment: @CommuSoft Sorry, I don't understand what you want. Please edit your question and add a detailed explanation of your intent.

Comment: Is the question more clear now?

Comment: @CommuSoft Yes, I think so ;-) please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a presentation using beamer, and at that time I use `varblock` environment, here one can write and include image in a certain location where ever you want.

By using `varblock`, I write 6 blocks and 3 of them was placed at the top and bottom blocks contains image. So the corresponding blocks contains the description of the image.

```
\begin{textblock}{}(1.1,2)
\begin{varblock}[5.5cm]{}
Any thing you can write OR
\includegraphics{your picture}
\end{varblock}
\end{textblock}
```

To declare `varblock`, you have to write the following command before `\begin{document}`.

```
\newenvironment<>{varblock}[2][\textwidth]{%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{#1}
  \begin{actionenv}#3%
    \def\insertblocktitle{#2}%
    \par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block begin}}
  {\par%
    \usebeamertemplate{block end}%
  \end{actionenv}}
```

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: your code contains %-characters that are comments. Does the code contains new lines at the end of those %-characters?

Comment: Furthermore `textblock is also an undefined environment.